# SQLite: how to manage groups?

Tags: sqlite

I'm creating a simple application, there is a table with file names, and a column with IDs of users allowed to read it, for example:

```
|FILES |USERS |
|my.txt|1,3,5 |
|fo.txt|3,4,17|
|ba.jpg|13,31 |
```

Is it right this way for creating user groups?

What is the right SQL statement to retrieve files allowed to user "3"?

Comment: What relation has "user groups" with your question?

Comment: Files is like a group, it works like a container for users...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't combine multiple values in one field.

Normal approach is:

```
|FILES |USERS|
|my.txt|1    |
|my.txt|3    |
|my.txt|5    |
|fo.txt|3    |
|fo.txt|4    |
|fo.txt|17   |
|ba.jpg|13   |
|ba.jpg|31   |
```

So if you want a list of files for user `3`, you do:

```
SELECT Files FROM Table WHERE User='3';
```

To check users for a file,

```
SELECT Users FROM Table WHERE File='my.txt';
```

Also common is to avoid repeating long strings, creating a new table `CREATE TABLE FileNames (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Filename)` and always referring ID instead of names in other tables. But that should be a performance evaluation made by you.

Answer (score 2):

You should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) the database. So you'll have

```
|FILE  |USER|
|my.txt|   1|
|my.txt|   3|
|my.txt|   5|
|fo.txt|   3|
...
```

That is simple normalization of the table you've shown. It does not involve any groups, but your original table didn't either.

Answer (score 0):

You should add separate 'groups' table:

```
|OID|group_id|user_id|
|  1|       1|      1|
|  2|       1|      2|
```

and reference this group in your files table. If you want to check specific user, it would be something like

```
select FILES from files join groups on files.group_id = groups.group_id where groups.user_id = 3
```

Comment: `join` without either `on`, `using` or `natural` is a cross join and return all combinations of files and groups.

Comment: Of course since the columns match, you can use `using (group_id)` instead of the `on` clause and since you want to use all columns with matching name, `natural join` is even shorter.